# Xamarin.Forms: can I declare an interface that has to be a ContentView

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, interface

I want to have an interface that's constrained to being a ContentView in Xamarin.Forms.

I'm thinking of something like this, but this itself doesn't work:

```
public interface InterfaceThatMustBeAContentView : ContentView
    {
        //....interfacey stuff
    }
```

I've done web searches for this a lot, but I always run into things talking about interface inheritance and subclass conformance, which aren't what I'm after.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that. But there are some related things you could do, depending on what you're trying to achieve.

```
public interface IMyThing1
{
    ContentView Thing { get; }
}

public interface IMyThing2<T> where T : ContentView
{
    T Thing { get; }
}
```

Or if you only need it to work with your own ContentView classes, and you don't need the interface to guarantee that it can be cast to a ContentView:

```
public interface IMyThing3
{
    // A few properties and methods that you know anything that inherits from ContentView will have
}

public class MyThing3 : IMyThing3, ContentView
{
}
```

Or if you just need to constrain a property or variable to being a ContentView then you don't need interfaces at all, just declare or cast it as a ContentView.

```
public void DoSomething(ContentView contentView)
{
    ContentView anotherContentView;
    // do something
}

public void DoSomethingToAFrame(Frame frame)
{
    DoSomething(frame);
}
```

Comment: To be (probably unnecessarily) tricky, using your first example, if I made a `ContentView` and declared it an `IMyThing1`, couldn't I then do`ContentView Thing { get { return this; }; }`?

Answer (score 1):

I can only think of this. it's an ugly solution but it answers your problem.

```
public interface InterfaceThatMustBeAContentView : 
IControlTemplated
ILayout, ILayoutController, IPaddingElement
IViewController, IGestureController, IGestureRecognizers
IAnimatable, IVisualElementController, IResourcesProvider, IStyleElement, IFlowDirectionController, IPropertyPropagationController, IVisualController, ITabStopElement
INavigationProxy, IStyleSelectable
IElement, INameScope, IElementController
INotifyPropertyChanged, IDynamicResourceHandler 
{
}
```

Comment: That's hilarious and I upvoted you just for cleverness.

Comment: In Winforms, I created a UserControl Interface called IUserControl where I could add my own custom methods. Essentially I created a Flyout type page where the IUserControl displayed the content but they all had common functions and events where I could just use the interface to control each one. So how would I do that in MAUI? Had a similar problem in Xamarin that I never solver as I just used the Flyout with some clever code to work things dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

**Kludgey Possibility**

This is just like Robyn's answer:

```
public interface IKludgeyContentViewInterface 
{
   ContentView ViewKludge { get; }
}
```

And it wouldn't *enforce* anything being a ContentView, but you could use it with a ContentView like so:

```
public ContentViewKludgeySubclass : ContentView, IKludgeyContentViewInterface 
{
   ContentView ViewKludge { get { return this; }; }
}
```

I know that's kinda dorky, what do you think?